# Does Apache Storm have machine learning libraries like with Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-storm, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I am comparing Apache Storm and Apache Spark streaming for choosing a distributed realtime computation system. There are already lots of discussion giving comparisons between these two technologies for instance stackoverflow.com/questions/24119897/apache-spark-vs-apache-storm/ . I am considering to choose Apache Storm because it is faster. However, I can't find if Apache Storm has machine learning libraries like with Apache Spark. Indeed, I want to do online machine learning and this is an important requirement.

Regards,

Yassir

Comment: I don't think Storm has any native ML.  Rather, through Bolts you have multi-language support and can use whatever is available in the language of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did you want to say , regarding your remark on the multi-language support, that I must implement ML algorithms by choosing a language?

Comment: More specifically, I think you must implement ML algorithms in your chosen language, whatever it is.  Could be R, python, etc..

Answer (score 3):

take a look at SAMOA (https://samoa.incubator.apache.org/). It's a third party machine learning library for Storm. It accepts other engines like Apache S4.